# ament_cmake: Confused about ament_export_dependencies and ament_export_interfaces

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm programming on ROS2 Dashing and trying to port some packages, but the [ament_cmake docs](https://index.ros.org//doc/ros2/Tutorials/Ament-CMake-Documentation/) haven't answered my questions

What does `ament_export_dependencies(my_target ...)` actually do?
Why is it needed if I already declared my dependencies with `ament_target_dependencies(my_target ...)` or `target_link_libraries(my_target PUBLIC ...)`?

Finally, why do I hardly see `ament_export_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME} HAS_LIBRARY_TARGET)` in the ROS2 codebase if that's the recommended way to expose library projects for downstream consumption?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331277/ament_cmake:-confused-about-ament_export_dependencies-and-ament_export_interfaces/) by [DanRose](https://answers.ros.org/users/43942/danrose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 274 on 2019-08-21

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your example you have `ament_export_dependencies(my_target)`, but that's incorrect. `ament_export_dependencies()` takes only package names.

In short,  `ament_target_dependencies()` sets up stuff for your package, `ament_export_dependencies()` and `ament_export_interfaces()` set up stuff for packages that depend on your package.

When a package calls [`find_package(MyDependency)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/find_package.html), CMake looks for a file called `mydependency-config.cmake` or `MyDependency-config.cmake`. [CMake documentation](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-to-create-a-ProjectConfig.cmake-file) calls this a ProjectConfig.cmake file. The ProjectConfig.cmake sets up everything another project would need to depend on this one. It [sets variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#standard-variable-names) like `MyDependency_INCLUDE_DIRS`, creates [imported targets](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/Exporting-and-Importing-Targets) like `MyDependency::somelibrary`, and finds packages `MyDependency` depends on.

First your package needs to use `MyDependency` when it's being built. `ament_target_dependencies(my_target MyDependency)` is a helper function that makes sure your executable or library has everything it needs to use `MyDependency`. It will call `target_link_libraries(my_target ${MyDependency_LIBRARIES})`, `target_include_directories(my_target PUBLIC ${MyDependency_INCLUDE_DIRS})`, etc.

Once your package is built/installed, other packages might need `MyDependency` too. For example, if your package includes `<my_depdenency/something.hpp>` in a header it installs, then packages that include your header will need to know where `MyDependency`'s headers are too. This is where `ament_export_dependencies()` comes in . Calling `ament_export_dependencies(MyDependency)` will make your package's ProjectConfig.cmake contain a `find_package(MyDependency)` call plus logic to combine CMake variables from `MyDependency` into your package's CMake variables. For example, it will make `YourPackage_INCLUDE_DIRS` contain everything in `MyDependency_INCLUDE_DIRS`. The purpose is so packages don't have to find your dependencies. Use `ament_export_dependencies()` on all dependencies of yours that downstream packages also need.

`ament_export_interfaces()` is a little different. This creates imported targets, which is a replacement for CMake standard variables in a ProjectConfig.cmake. It will likely be used more in the future, but for now [there is at least one issue](https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/issues/183) with it that needs to be fixed. It won't replace `ament_export_dependencies()`, but it will change how information like include directories and libraries are communicated between packages.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2019-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DanRose](https://answers.ros.org/users/43942/danrose/) on 2019-08-21**:
Thank you! So what about the PUBLIC/PRIVATE/INTERFACE specifiers on `target_link_libraries` and `target_include_directories`? What effect (if any) do these have on consumers of my package/library?

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2019-08-21**:
My understanding of those is lacking. On consumers of your package? I think the keywords only have an effect on consumers if your package export targets. They do have an effect within targets of your package, but the CMake documentation for [`target_include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/target_include_directories.html) and [`https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/target_link_libraries.html`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/target_link_libraries.html) probably explains better than I can.

**Comment by [DanRose](https://answers.ros.org/users/43942/danrose/) on 2019-08-21**:
I submitted an issue, as this seems like a bug that it affects people who link to my library via ament_target_dependencies but not via target_link_libraries. https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/issues/189

**Comment by [strike_eagle_iii](https://answers.ros.org/users/38642/strike_eagle_iii/) on 2022-05-27**:
when you say ament_export_dependencies takes only package names, does it only take ros package names or can it take system installed dependencies such Eigen, OpenCV, or my own custom non-ros2 libraries?